# Is there a way to connect to multiple databases in multiple hosts using Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, informix, apache-kafka-connect

I have a need to get data from Informix database using Kafka Connect. The scenario is this - I have 50 Informix Databases residing in 50 hosts. What I have understood by reading from Kafka connect is that we need to install the Kafka connect in each hosts to get the data from the database residing in that host. My question is this - Is there a way in which I can create the connectors centrally for these 50 hosts instead of installing into each of them and pull data from the databases?

Comment: Where did you read that you needed to install Connect on your database hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect JDBC does not have to run on the database, just as other JDBC clients don't, so you can a have a Kafka Connect cluster be larger or smaller than your database pool.

Informix seems to have a thing called "CDC Replication Engine for Kafka", however, which might be something worth looking into, as CDC overall causes less load on the database

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need any additional software installation on the system where Informix server is running.I am not fully clear about the question or the type of operation you are plan to do. If you are planning to setup a real time replication type of scenario, then you may have to invoke CDC API. Then one-time setup of CDC API at server is needed, then this APIs can be invoked using any Informix database driver API. If you are plan to read existing data from table(s) and pump into Kafka topic, then no need of any additional setup at server side. You could connect to all 50 database server(s) from a single program (remotely) and then pump those records to the Kafka topic(s). Base on the program language you are using you may choose Informix database driver.